# Solving easy first-order linear differential question.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Question**

Solve $y'=2x(1+x^2-y)$.

**My attempt**

Rearranging gives $y'+2xy=2x(1+x^2)$. Thus, the integrating factor is $e^{\int2x\,dx}=e^{x^2}$ and multiplying the equation throughout by this gives

$e^{x^2}y'+2xe^{x^2}y=2xe^{x^2}(1+x^2)\Rightarrow\dfrac{d}{dx}{e^{x^2}y}=2xe^{x^2}+2x^3e^{x^2}$ which is separable.

Then,

$e^{x^2}y=\int2xe^{x^2}\,dx+2\int x^3e^{x^2}\,dx=e^{x^2}+2\int x^3e^{x^2}\,dx$

Is this correct and is there some easy way of working out $\int x^3e^{x^2}\,dx$? Wolfram has it as $e^{x^2}(x^2-1)$.

Maybe I write $2x^3e^{x^2}$ as $x(2x^2e^{x^2})$?

Comment: In the integral, change of vatiable $t=x^2$ and you can integrate.

Comment: Attention for $e^{\int2x\,dx}=e^{x^2}$. Is not it $e^{\int2x\,dx}=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$ ?

Comment: @optimalcontrol No it's not. The differential of $x^2$ is $2x$, the differential of $\frac{x^2}{2}$ is $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct.

in your last decomposition substitute $u=x^2$ to get $\int u e^u du$ and apply integration by parts

Answer (score 1):

make a change of variable $$1+x^2 - y = u, \quad y =1+x^2 - u, y' = 2x-u' $$ then the de $y' = 2x(1+x^2 - y)$ is turned into $$2x-u' = 2xu $$ multiplying by $e^{x^2},$  we get $$e^{x^2}(u'+2xu) = \left(e^{x^2}u\right)' = 2xe^{x^2}$$ on integration yields $$e^{x^2}u = e^{x^2} + c\to u = 1+ce^{-x^2},\quad y = x^2 -ce^{-x^2} $$

Answer (score 0):

$$y'+2xy=2x(1+x^2)$$
now we will find the complementary solution as follow
$$y'+2xy=0$$
$$\frac{y'}{y}=-2x$$
$$\log y=-x^2+C_1$$
hence
$$y_c=Ce^{-x^2}$$
to find the paticular solution ,assume $y_p=Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$

then find the $A,B,C,D$